# Create mesh from point cloud

Tags: mesh, construction

I have a set of points that need to be constructed as a set of triangular faces to form a solid mesh. I have looked at Delaunay Triangulation and none of it makes sense.
Any advice on where to begin? I am not dealing with complex shapes, they consist of 200 vertices max.

Note: the points are in x,y,z space.

Comment: Do you want to create a solid 3d mesh, filling a volume, or do you want to describe a surface?

Answer (score 5):

There are variety of options to construct mesh from vertices:
1: You can use Poisson reconstruction 
http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~misha/Code/PoissonRecon/Version5.7/
it is also implemented meshlab which is open source http://gmv.cast.uark.edu/scanning/point-clouds-to-mesh-in-meshlab/ and also in PCL http://pointclouds.org/
2: Another option is marching cubes, you can also find an implementation in PCL